# Matching second occurrence in javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm completely new to regexps and syntax melts my brain, so basically i have a string which looks like this

`randomtext WORD randomtext WORD neededtext BORDERWORD randomtext`

Where **word** and **borderword** are different from each other, other stuff is self explanatory.

I've got as far as `/(.?(WORD)){2}((.|\n)*)BORDERWORD/` but it doesn't work.

Another problem is that both **randomtext** and **neededtext**  contain newline characters, which i think i solved in the  matching group that tries to match **neededtext** `((.|\n)*)` but have no idea how to make it work in the first one.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: figured out a workaround, first match `word((.|\n)*)borderword` and then match the result with `word((.|\n)*)` Done. Doesn't seem right but it works for my purposes.

Comment: To include newline characters, use `[\s\S]*?`

Comment: I'm afraid i'm blown out of the water by this stuff. Could you elaborate or better yet provide a working expression for my scenario?

Comment: Could there be multiple instances of WORD neededtext BORDERWORD in the sample string?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
\bWORD\s*((?:(?!WORD)(?:.|\n))*?)\s*BORDERWORD\b
```

It makes sure that you want to extract text between *WORD* and *BORDERWORD*, and that text does not contain another WORD sequence.

Capturing group 1 will contain the needed text

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD6pC7/1)

Comment: Damn, there is some weird stuff happening with cyrillic text i think.  
Your example with swapped words for my actual ones [https://regex101.com/r/lD6pC7/3](https://regex101.com/r/lD6pC7/3)  
My actual string with words swapped [https://regex101.com/r/lD6pC7/2](https://regex101.com/r/lD6pC7/2)

Comment: @mouzfun You're going to have issues with certain unicode chars in JavaScript regex. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/4959722) for some possible solutions.

Comment: Damn, at this point i think it might be easier to use .split. Also it matches fine with `word((.|\n)*)borderword` , it's that damned first occurance that ruins everything, maybe there is some workaround? Also, randomtext and neededtext can't contain both word and borderword

Comment: figured it out, first match `word((.|\n)*)borderword` and then match the result with `word((.|\n)*)` Done. Doesn't seem right but it works for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "randomtext WORD randomtext WORD neededtext BORDERWORD randomtext";
var matches = str.match(/^.+? WORD .+? WORD (.+?) BORDERWORD/);
console.log(matches[1]); // neededtext
```